# Заувага =зауваження?

Tags: різниця-між-словами, віддієслівні-іменники

Цікавить питання:  в якому контексті ми можемо вживати "**заувага**", а в якому -"**зауваження"**?

У [Словнику синонімів Караванського](http://slovopedia.org.ua/41/53399/265339.html) знаходимо, що ці слова синоніми.
 А [Ігор Ребезнюк у статті СПРОБУЙМО ПИСАТИ ТА ГОВОРИТИ ЗА НАЦІОНАЛЬНИМИ, А НЕ РАДЯНСЬКИМИ ПРАВИЛАМИ](http://tc.terminology.lp.edu.ua/TK_Zbirnyk_2014/TK_Zbirnyk_2014_3_rebeznuk.htm) зауважує:

> Якщо розглядати як дію-подію-наслідок тріаду слів **зауважування-зауваження-заувага**, то видно, що **зауваження** – це подія, а наслідок цієї події, що є коротко висловлене чи записане судження з приводу чого-небудь, – **заувага.**

Отже, автор не вважає ці слова синонімами.

Як тоді нормативно вживати ці слова у контексті?

Comment: Див. також: [«Як бути з віддієслівними іменниками на -ння, -ття?»](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/3084).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У [СУМі-20](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=135806&page=1070) подають такі визначення:

> **ЗАУВА́ГА**, рідше ЗАВВА́ГА, и, ж. ***Те саме, що заува́ження***. Нарешті, кілька завваг з приводу словотвору (В. Русанівський);
>
> – Товаришу Шторе, ви запізнились на двадцять хвилин. Роблю вам заввагу (В. Винниченко)
>
> **ЗАУВА́ЖЕННЯ**, я, с.1. Коротко висловлене судження, міркування з приводу чого-небудь.
>
> Огей і Орест тупцяли довгим коридором.., перекидаючись зауваженнями про плакати, які висіли на стінах (Олесь Досвітній)
>
> // перев. мн.Судження наукового, публіцистичного і т. ін. характеру про який-небудь твір.
>
> Комітет в справах мистецтв дав мій переклад на рецензію якомусь N. Цей “рецензент” написав зауважень на цілих шістдесят, а то й більше, сторінок (Остап Вишня).
>
> 2. Докір, закид, указівка на помилку в поведінці.
>
> В довірливих розмовах Світлана завжди критикувала інших. Якогось разу Тарас це помітив і зробив їй зауваження (Ю. Покальчук)
>
> // Міра стягнення, покарання за який-небудь учинок.
>
> До школи він, звичайно, запізнився .. Але вчитель географії був суворіший за вчителя історії, він .. записав йому зауваження (О. Іваненко)

[На офіційному сайті Української мови](https://ukrainskamova.com/publ/slovnik_sinonimiv/z/zauvazhennja/31-1-0-4073) пишуть, що:

> Синонiм до слова **ЗАУВАЖЕННЯ**: **заувага**, репліка, сил. докір, закид, вказівка; (суворе) догана.

У [Словнику синонімів української мови](http://synonyms_uk.enacademic.com/6227/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%96%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0) читаємо:

> примітка (додаток, пояснення до якогось твору / тексту, перев. коротке), коментар, **зауваження**, **заувага**; ремарка (перев. у драматичному творі).

Виходячи з вищенаведених словників, *заувага і зауваження — це синоніми*, єдина відмінність у самому “відтінку” (про що йдеться у статті, яку Ви згадуєте): *зауваження — це подія, заувага — наслідок події, що є коротко висловлене чи записане судження з приводу чого-небудь*. Таким чином їх можна замінювати одне одним. Наприклад: "я врахую Ваше зауваження" і "я врахую Вашу заувагу".